# Allocating numbers with specific exact proportion to a list of IDs with classes

Tags: r

I have a problem in R.
I want to allocate "1" and "2" randomly to a list of numbers (1:6000). The numbers are classified into 3 groups (2000 numbers per class). I want to do the random allocation in such a way that: in class 1, 25% of the numbers get "1" and 75% get "2"; in class 2 50% of of the numbers get "1" and the rest get "2"; in class 3, 75% get "1" and 25% get "2".
I would appreciate any help on this issue

the data looks like this:

id  class
1   1
2   1
3   1
.   1
.   1
.   1
2000    1

2001    2
2002    2
2003    2
.   2
.   2
.   2
4000    2

4001    3
4002    3
4003    3
.   3
.   3
.   3
6000    3

Cheers,
Hamed

Answer (score 0):

you can create vectors with the numbers that you want and then use the function *sample* to allocate the numbers randomly. You can use set.seed(x) to give you the same allocation each time.

```
 s1 <- c(rep(1,4), rep(2,12))
 s2 <- c(rep(1,8), rep(2,8))
 s3 <- c(rep(1, 12), rep(2, 4))

 s <- c(sample(s1), sample(s2), sample(s3))

 # or you could set the seed
 set.seed(42)
 s <- c(sample(s1), sample(s2), sample(s3))
```

Comment: It did, thank you! I have a more complicated question if you don't mind! I have a list of numbers (1:10000). The numbers are classified into 100 groups, so that in each group contains 100 numbers. The groups are again classified randomly into 3 sub-groups (h.1, h.2, h.3). I want to allocate random numbers (1/2) to the individual of the group as follows: 75% of Individuals in h.1 get “1” and the rest get “2”, 50% of individuals in h.2 get “1”, 25% of individuals in h.3 get  “1”. note that I'd like to allocate numbers with specific proportion to the numbers in each group. I hope is clear. Thanks

Comment: you can do that with a for loop and if statements

Comment: `s = c()
for( i in 1:100){
x = sample(1:3, 1)
if(x == 1){ s = c(s, sample(s1)) }
else if( x == 2){ s = c(s, sample(s2))}
else { s = c(s, sample(s3))}
}`